# Azure web application authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have enabled azure web authentication in my web application and when unauthenticated users tried to access it, azure redirects it to `https://example.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback` page and shows the message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

For non-authorized users, instead of showing above message I want to redirect to another custom page to show another message.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Tushar

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately , Azure AD doesn't support this feature for now.

I understand what you want to achieve. You can upvote this idea in [this User Voice Page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32128597-allow-for-customized-error-messages-in-azure-ad-co). Azure AD Team will review it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

ACS gives you error messages in encoded JSON like this

{"context":null,"httpReturnCode":401,"identityProvider":"Google","timeStamp":"2010-12-17 21:01:36Z","traceId":"16bba464-03b9-48c6-a248-9d16747b1515","errors":[{"errorCode":"ACS30000","errorMessage":"There was an error processing an OpenID sign-in response."},{"errorCode":"ACS50019","errorMessage":"Sign-in was canceled by the user."}]}

1. First you need to enable the "Error URL feature" in management portal, for your ACS namespace-> Edit Relying party-> Error URL.
2. You need a helper classes to decode the JSON. [steps here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg185925.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
3. Configure anon access to them Error page.

With this you will have full control of the page, you can show the error message the way wants and brand the page to match the look and feel of your relying party web.

Comment: Wasn't ACS already discontinued basically? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/acs-access-control-service-namespace-creation-restriction/